# text2vec in R- Transform new data?

Tags: r, text-mining, text2vec

There is documentation on creating a DTM (document term matrix) for the text2vec package, for example the following where a TFIDF weighting is applied after building the matrix:

```
data("movie_review")
N <- 1000
it <- itoken(movie_review$review[1:N], preprocess_function = tolower,
tokenizer = word_tokenizer)
v <- create_vocabulary(it)
vectorizer <- vocab_vectorizer(v)
it <- itoken(movie_review$review[1:N], preprocess_function = tolower,
tokenizer = word_tokenizer)
dtm <- create_dtm(it, vectorizer)
# get tf-idf matrix from bag-of-words matrix
dtm_tfidf <- transformer_tfidf(dtm)
```

It is common practice to create a DTM based on a training dataset and use that dataset as input to a model. Then, when new data is encountered (a test set) one needs to create the same DTM on the new data (meaning all the same terms that were used in the training set). Is there anyway in the package to transform a new data set in this manner (in scikit we have a transform method for just this type of instance).

Comment: Any guts to explain why downvoted?

Comment: Doesn't take "guts" to explain. Just hover your your pointer over the down-arrow. Many possibilities for taking offense at that question. No code. No example data. No explanation of what sort of model building or scoring might be anticipated. No explanation of what a "DTM" is.... yeah, I know what it (probably) is, but many programmers might not. So I have to agree it is at the very least "unclear" and also not much `research effort` demonstrated, and those are perfectly valid reasons for a downvote. Also seems rather useless unless is it expanded to address its many deficiencies.

Comment: Hovering doesnt show me anything? Its frustrating when someone down votes without explanation. This type of question is focused on a specific package, where my assumption is if you have used it and could remotely answer the question, you would know what a document term matrix was. Code is also a tough one....since what I am wondering isnt like here is some code, what is wrong with it - but instead, can the package do 'x'. I will try to expand it somewhat though and I thank you for the comments.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter. When I downvote I usually leave an explanation. I agree it frustrating not to see an explanation but it's also frustrating to see _many_ questions by people who obviously have not read the help and introductory pages for SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually when I started `text2vec` I kept that pipeline at the first place. Now we are preparing new release with updated [documentation](https://github.com/lmullen/text2vec/blob/c33984cd8f70f715d7f0bb1df593ddabe6e4d257/vignettes/text-vectorization.Rmd).

For v0.3 following should work:

```
data("movie_review")
train_rows = 1:1000
prepr = tolower
tok = word_tokenizer

it <- itoken(movie_review$review[train_rows], prepr, tok, ids = movie_review$id[train_rows])
v <- create_vocabulary(it) %>% 
  prune_vocabulary(term_count_min = 5)

vectorizer <- vocab_vectorizer(v)
it <- itoken(movie_review$review[train_rows], prepr, tok)
dtm_train <- create_dtm(it, vectorizer)
# get idf scaling from train data
idf = get_idf(dtm_train)
# create tf-idf
dtm_train_tfidf <- transform_tfidf(dtm_train, idf)

test_rows = 1001:2000
# create iterator
it <- itoken(movie_review$review[test_rows], prepr, tok, ids = movie_review$id[test_rows])
# create dtm using same vectorizer, but new iterator
dtm_test_tfidf <- create_dtm(it, vectorizer) %>% 
  # transform  tf-idf using idf from train data
  transform_tfidf(idf)
```

Comment: Fantastic! Any idea when it may hit CRAN?

Comment: Few weeks.  But you can install it from github, branch 0.4.

Comment: @B_Miner check new tutorial: http://dsnotes.com/text2vec/vectorization.html

Comment: Now text2vec v0.4 on CRAN